# Can't make collision between enemy and player do damage to the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthBarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] heartContainers;
    private Image[] heartFills;

    public Transform heartsParent;
    public GameObject heartContainerPrefab;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Should I use lists? Maybe :)
        heartContainers = new GameObject[(int)PlayerStats.Instance.MaxTotalHealth];
        heartFills = new Image[(int)PlayerStats.Instance.MaxTotalHealth];

        PlayerStats.Instance.onHealthChangedCallback += UpdateHeartsHUD;
        InstantiateHeartContainers();
        UpdateHeartsHUD();
    }

    public void UpdateHeartsHUD()
    {
        SetHeartContainers();
        SetFilledHearts();
    }

    void SetHeartContainers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < heartContainers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < PlayerStats.Instance.MaxHealth)
            {
                heartContainers[i].SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                heartContainers[i].SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    void SetFilledHearts()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < heartFills.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < PlayerStats.Instance.Health)
            {
                heartFills[i].fillAmount = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                heartFills[i].fillAmount = 0;
            }
        }

        if (PlayerStats.Instance.Health % 1 != 0)
        {
            int lastPos = Mathf.FloorToInt(PlayerStats.Instance.Health);
            heartFills[lastPos].fillAmount = PlayerStats.Instance.Health % 1;
        }
     }

    void InstantiateHeartContainers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < PlayerStats.Instance.MaxTotalHealth; i++)
        {
            GameObject temp = Instantiate(heartContainerPrefab);
            temp.transform.SetParent(heartsParent, false);
            heartContainers[i] = temp;
            heartFills[i] = temp.transform.Find("HeartFill").GetComponent<Image>();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `HealthbarController` and it works when the damage is a button. Same with `heal` and `addheart` but I can't make my enemies do the damage.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DamageScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Hurt(float dmg)
    {
        PlayerStats.Instance.TakeDamage(dmg);
    }
}
```

and this is the damage script for my enemies. How can I make enemy do damage to the player when colliding with the player? I tried with `OnCollisionEnter` but whenever I put it into the code I only got a bunch of errors.

Comment: and what has rigidbodies on it? and what were the errors and oncollissionenter would be the right thing

Comment: Oh sorry there were no errors more that nothing happened :( What do you mean "what has rigidbodies on it?" I don't understand :/

Comment: you dont just put colliders on, have a read up on collissions in unity

Comment: You said:  _I put it into the code I only got a bunch of errors._.  What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried giving your enemy the tag "Enemy" and your player a sphere collider (isTrigger checked).

And then make a take damage script for example:

```
public class takeDamage : MonoBehaviour
{     

private int PlayerHp = 10f;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag( "Enemy")) {
                PlayerHp -= 1;
                Debug.Log("Hit, HP: " + PlayerHp);
               //Add GUI update function here
            }

        }
}
```

and attach it to the player.

Don't forget to scale the sphere collider to the appropriate size.

Comment: The thing is I cant use int as it is already declared as an float and I cant convert it. :/

Comment: And gameobject does not contain a definition so the collider don't work :(

Comment: Just make it a double, also what do you mean does not contain a definition